# How to get the element value of certain tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example i have this code

```
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="monday" aria-pressed="true">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Monday
</label>
```

I want to get the value of "aria-pressed" i want to return if it's true or false.

I tried something like this that i thought it would work but obviously it's wrong.

```
document.getElementById("monday").aria-pressed
```

Comment: `.getAttribute('attributeName')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.getAttribute()`:

```
document.querySelector("#monday").getAttribute('aria-pressed');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/3Lv5zy5e/

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. Its an attribute.

Comment: @user3080440 you should accept one of the answers if it solved your issue. Happy to help!

Comment: Selected. Didnt noticed the check icon at first. I just upvoted it. lol

Comment: Why am i getting null result if i do this.

var dayIfActive = document.getElementById("monday").getAttribute('aria-pressed');
            console.log(dayIfActive);

Answer (score 2):

use the `getAttribute()` method

```
document.getElementById("monday").getAttribute('aria-pressed');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: Duplicate of my answer.

Comment: all the answers are the same. they were also all posted the same minute. what is your point.

Comment: They were not posted the same second, however.

Comment: They were less than 20 seconds off. and if anything your answer is a copy of  Gerardo comment

Comment: 8 and 14 seconds behind mine, but who is counting? ;^) I had not seen Gerardo's comment when I posted my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've returned the favor.

Answer (score 1):

The aria-pressed is attribute on the label element, hence you will need to use getAttribute method.

document.getElementById("monday").getAttribute('aria-pressed')

Comment: Duplicate of my answer.